# How to link to another document (within same site collection and may b within same doc lib)

Tags: document-library, file-upload

I have 4 records in excel and they all have same pdf files. I can import all 4 records and alter the file name so all the records can be import. All that fine. Now, I was thinking why not import the first record with file and rest of the 3 records without file and have reference to 1st record.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Link To A Document content type can fulfill your need.
Check out this [post](http://mossdevsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/05/link-to-document-in-another-folder-in.html) and [this](http://www.sharepointology.com/general/link-to-a-document-in-another-document-library/) one too

Comment: I certainly give those links a try and see how it works out. I may have to change my script to get the filelink from the first file and they associate with other 3 files.